# When measuring a resistor with a multimeter does polarity matter?

Tags: resistors, multimeter

When measuring the resistance of a resistor using a multimeter does it matter if I turned the resistor around and have the probes at opposite leads?

Should I get the same results?

Comment: I recommend you to test it and find out. Especially since the question is part of your experiment :)

Comment: If the resistor is in circuit, the circuitry around it (including diodes, transistors, ICs) can make a difference when you swap the meter probes around.

Answer (score 8):

A simple resistor has no polarity as far as its resistance is concerned.  The resistance is the same regardless of the orientation of the probes across it.

Answer (score 3):

With an ordinary resistor, you should get the same answer both ways round.

If the leads and probes have different surface impurities, or finger-grease, you may set up enough contact voltage to disturb the reading a little.

Lead temperature effects, while possible, should be below the resolution of most meters.

Resistor diode effects should only appear in the most horrible old corroded resistors.

Answer (score 0):

Yes resistance as a electrical property can in certain circumstances have polarity, tested by swapping probes and finding that polarity swaps.

The slightly strange circumstance occurs with a LDR optocoupler type NSL32SR3  and you seek to power the circuit from the same resistance you are creating.This suggests a improbable state, a bit like already being across the road looking back,to where you were before you were crossing it, But the by product is creation of a resistance with polarity.

Comment: Your answer is a bit off topic, and is already commented on 7years ago.